# zsh: unknown file attribute

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have the following function in my `.zshrc` which, in theory, allows me to write a commit message without needing quotation marks.

```
cm(){
    git commit -m "$@"
}
```

When I run it (`cm foo bar`), I get the following error:

```
zsh: unknown file attribute
```

Does `$@` mean the same thing in zsh as it does in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accoring to [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) article, `*` and `@` both contain an array of the positional parameters.

> The parameters `*`, `@` and `argv` are arrays containing all the positional parameters; thus `$argv[n]`, etc., is equivalent to simply `$n`.

And...

> A subscript of the form `[*]` or `[@]` evaluates to all elements of an array; there is no difference between the two except when they appear within double quotes. `"$foo[*]"` evaluates to `"$foo[1] $foo[2] ..."`, whereas `"$foo[@]"` evaluates to `"$foo[1]" "$foo[2]" ...`.

Comment: That seems to work now with ${*} instead of $*. I wonder why zsh would implement this differently.

Comment: You mean that you substituted "$@" in your code with "${@}"?

Comment: No sorry that was confusing. I substituted `"$@"` with `"${*}"`. I put the wrong thing in my comment because that's what I started with. I just switched $* to $@ when I was troubleshooting. As I understand it, $@ is like an array and $* is a space-separated string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are also getting this similar error `zsh: unknown file attribute: 1` while running a command then it may be due to character `(` and `)`

For me I was trying to delete a git remote branch with name `example-(123)` it throws the above mentioned error, you can fix it by wrapping the branch name in single/double quotes e.g below

`git push --delete origin "example-(123)"`